# How to change the default complier compliance level for the current workspace in Hydrograph?

Tags: github

While creating my first project using [Hydrograph](https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph), I saw default compiler compliance level for the current workspace message in the create project window.

> **Complete Error message:**
>
> `The default compiler compliance level for the current workspace is 1.4. The new project will use a project specific compiler compliance level of 1.8.`

The help file/document that comes along with the tool does not explain how do change the default complier compliance level for the current workspace.

I have explored all tabs/options listed under Window --> Preference section but couldn't locate any settings that could `change the CCLevel of the default workspace`. As the error says all new `projects` will be created with CClevel 1.8, `The question still remains is how to change the default CCLevel of the workspace`.

The compiler option present under Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler shows the compiler compliance level pointing towards 1.8, which I strongly feel that this is for the project and not for the workspace (Error is about workspace and not for project)

Reported Issue is [here](https://github.com/capitalone/Hydrograph/issues/159).

Hydrograph Create ELT Project Window
[image: Hydrograph Create ELT Project Window]

Hydrograph Preferences Window
[image: Hydrograph Preferences Window]

-ira wati

Answer (score 0):

Hydrograph is built on Eclipse plugin development framework and the message you see their is coming from existing eclipse plugin(i.e. the plugin which facilitates creation of project and this plugin is part of eclipse framework). You might be able to see this message as Hydrograph is designed to work on JDK8 and above, to function well.

Note- it requires JDK not JRE. You will be able to see normal Job is executing smoothly with JRE, but you wont be able to create transform. You wont be able to see existing transform classes or you may face issue with expression editor if you are not using JDK8+.